# How to use dynamic array index in for and if statement because i got Undefined offset: 1 in laravel blade

Tags: laravel

i'm new in laravel, i got a situation when i want to access the array using variable, i got Undefined offset: 1 error.

how to use index in for and if statement?

Here is my code.

```
@for($i = 0; $i< count($type['layout']); $i++)
   @if($type['layout']['col'] == 1)
      @if($type['layout']['properties'][$i]['type'] == "text")
         text input
      @else if($type['layout']['properties'][0]['type'] == "radio")
         radio btn
      @endif
   @endif
@endfor
```

Array Format is here

```
array:1 [▼
   "layout" => array:2 [▼
   "col" => "1"
   "properties" => array:1 [▼
        0 => array:3 [▼
           "type" => "text"
           "label" => "username"
           "text" => "Enter your username"
         ]
      ]
   ]
]
```

[Here is the image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg4b4.png)

Comment: i also try to access data in if statement like this:
@if($type['layout']['properties'][{{$i}}]['type'] == "text")
@if($type['layout']['properties'][.$i.]['type'] == "text")
etc.
but nothing gonna work for me.

Comment: can u show whole array in question @umar Aslam

Comment: maybe you could better do `dd($type)` and edit your question

Comment: Question updated as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Given the data example you dont need a loop? You should also be able to flatten the first array in properties. Consider this example:
web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome')->with('type', [
        "layout" => [
            "col" => 1,
            "properties" => [
                    "type" => "text",
                    "label" => "Label",
                    "text" => "Username"
            ]
        ]
    ]);
});
```

welcome.blade.php

```
@if($type['layout']['col'] == 1)
    @if($type['layout']['properties']['type'] == "text")
        text input
    @else if($type['layout']['properties']['type'] == "radio")
        radio btn
    @endif
@endif
```

Let me know if that helps you or if I misunderstood something.

Comment: it's wrong answer, I suppose if it's array it could be many layouts and many properties..

Comment: @Anders the data is coming dynamically from database, first i decode it in json and then i pass that decoded data to view.
so i have to work with index.

Comment: Ok, got it Ill have another look. It would be helpful if you could replace the Array format with json

Comment: change the format isn't the solution, on stackoverflow, there are hundred and thousands of programmers and i think they have the solution of that little problem. I think i can't escaped from the problem and also i can't change the format, changing in json format is mine last opotion.

Comment: @Aleksandrs yes though example shows an associative array rather than an indexed array. Maybe im reading the dd() formatting wrong. And many properties are already fitted inside the properties second level?

Comment: Got it umar, it was just for clarity since the current format is some kind of output generated for html display. Not for you to change your code, rather the example code of the question. Sorry for the hastle

Answer (score 0):

You missed the loop key. Chang to this:

```
$type['layout'][$i]['col'] == 1
```

You missed loop key in this line: `@if($type['layout']['col'] == 1)`

[image]

Comment: the key isn't missing, i'm just testing it with custom values like 0,1,2 and so on. when i use $i it gives me an error Undefined offset: 1

Comment: And you can see solution in my answer because of [this](https://i.imgur.com/pzDWP41.png).

Comment: Because wrong code is used. 
Post again your error image. In error image you have already posted, you are not using code I have provided in answer.

Comment: @umarAslam Have you seen this image? Did it helped you solve the issue?